# How can I get all of them after the second "_" separation in a string data in mssql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this in a string column in a table: `[Product] -> "LA100_Runner_35C924_D"`. From this data I want to get the data after the second `_`, so I want to get `35C924_D`.

How do I do that?

I tried `WHERE [Product] LIKE '%_%' escape ''` but I couldn't quite get it working. I can't think of what I want with the LIKE operation.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: `LIKE` is not a regex, and the SQL language does not provide regex-like extractions. Some database platforms have this as an extension to the standard language, but SQL Server is not one of them. Therefore you'll need to get creative and put together some raw string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to apply the combination of `SUBSTRING` + `PATINDEX` twice on the same strings, while splitting on the first underscore symbol as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[_]%', string)+1, LEN(string)) AS string
    FROM tab
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, PATINDEX('%[_]%', string)+1, LEN(string))
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jJPaGZfV).

---

You can also do the same using `RIGHT` + `PATINDEX` in a very similar fashion:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT RIGHT(string, LEN(string) - PATINDEX('%[_]%', string)) AS string
    FROM tab
)
SELECT RIGHT(string, LEN(string) - PATINDEX('%[_]%', string)) AS string
FROM cte
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/jrb--fWY).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that is using tokenization via XML and XQuery.

The XPath predicate `[position() ge 3]` is asking to get all tokens starting from the 3rd.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Product VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (Product) VALUES
('LA100_Runner_35C924_D'),
('MA200_Runner_77C924_D');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '_';

SELECT t.* 
    , Result = REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() ge 3])')
        .value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'), SPACE(1), @separator)
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(Product, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | Product | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LA100_Runner_35C924_D | 35C924_D |
| 2 | MA200_Runner_77C924_D | 77C924_D |